# JQuery UI - How to contain a draggable in multiple(yet same class) divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Example:

```
<div>
    <div class='drop'>
        <div class='drag'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='drop'>
    </div>
    <div class='drop'>
    </div>
    <div class='drop'>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that the "div.drag" can only be dragged/dropped inside a "div.drop" element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in your javascript:

```
$('div.drop').droppable({ accept: 'div.drag' });
```

**Update:**

To have the element revert back to its original position if not dropped on a valid element:

```
$('.drag').draggable({
  snap: '.drop',
  revert: 'invalid'
});
```

Comment: The problem is not how to accept but rather how to make the drag element only drop inside one of the divs. Right now, it seems that when I pass a class selector, it only allows it to be contained by the first encountered element that matches the selector rather than on what element it was dropped in.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to revert the draggable to its initial, pre-drag position if it's not dropped into a valid element. Not entirely convinced this is what you're after..